# Can I use my Windows anti-virus program to scan my Android device?

Tags: android, anti-virus

I have been searching anti-virus software which could enable me to clean the cell phone by using my PC/Laptop.

Already I've tried Quick Heal's "PC to Mobile" but unable to execute on my Phone !

Comment: Mobile OS is different than OS on PC. This is why all software are developed separately for PC and mobile devices. Almost all antivirus companies provide separate antivirus software for mobile devices. You can download your preferred antivirus from play store.

Comment: See this...https://www.avast.com/en-us/android

Comment: Requests for software recommendations are off-topic.  Whether or not a specific program will do what you want is something that can be tested or checked in the specs.  "Does such a capability exist" is effectively a product request.  "Is it theoretically possible" is a pretty iffy question as far as being on-topic.  The best place to ask this would be the software rec site.

Comment: Thanks to all for responding the Question, finally I got the solution the Quick Heal anti virus software  "PC-to-Mobile", is now working properly.

Comment: @RajeshS, great that you got it working.  Consider closing the loop on your question by posting an answer and accepting it.  Explain how you discovered what the underlying problem was and how you got it to work.  That could provide value to other readers with a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

It is doubtful if you are speaking of the default Windows antivirus program.  There are other Windows compatible virus programs that do include an application you can download onto your mobile device, however, the default Windows antivirus programs do not support mobile devices.

Comment: I'm looking for the software which could scan the Android Phone and I've tried Quick Heal's PC to MOBILE software, it  supports both Windows as well as Android , but unable to clean the Phone storage !!

Comment: Try this.... http://www.symantec-norton.com/Norton_Mobile_Security_2012_p116.aspx?par=goo_usbroad9278942328_norton_mobile_security&par1=en_us_norton_mobile_security_promotion&gclid=Cj0KCQjw0PTXBRCGARIsAKNYfG3HOk2mdRQfRTaBBpiduAwchZ7_tZq8Q9MSdcYALMA2BSrOaIrG2cAaAiViEALw_wcB

Answer (score 0):

You can, with some limitations.

1. connect your Android device to the pc
2. install an [app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.theolivetree.webdavserver&hl=en) that acts as a WebDAV server
3. start the WebDAV server on the Android device
4. fire up Windows Explorer on the pc
5. click on Computer -> Map Network Drive
6. enter the address that appears on the app, then click Finish
7. in Windows Explorer, right-click on the drive letter that has appeared, and select *Scan with your antivirus*

**Limitations:**

- The WebDAV server does not expose *all* files on the Android device. Luckily, those locations that can be shared are precisely where viruses are most likely to have been saved by a user or an app.
- You are using a Windows antivirus, which may be optimized to look for Windows-specific threats. It may not detect different threats specifically targeted at Linux or Android.